# Django render DecimalFields

Tags: django, django-models, sum, django-context

My code, models.py

```
class accounts(models.Model):
    paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

Views.py

```
def home(request):
    template = "index.html"
    total_paid = Accounts.aggregate(Sum('paid'))
    total_balance = Accounts.aggregate(Sum('balance'))
    return render_to_response(template, context_instance=RequestContext(request,locals()))
```

And index.html

```
 {{ total_balance }}
 {{ total_paid }}
```

I want to render the amount of this fields on all users , so i use "Sum" , and i want to render it , but when i do it doesnt render the raw value , for some reason i cant undestand they return {'balance__sum': Decimal('0.00')} , i suppose its "Sum's" fault i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregate returns a dictionary as defined  here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/. So if you want to render is you can do the following

```
def home(request):
    template = "index.html"
    total_paid = Accounts.objects.all()aggregate(Sum('paid'))
    total_balance = Accounts.objects.all()aggregate(Sum('balance'))

    context ('total_paid': total_paid['paid_sum'],
             'total_balance': total_balance['balance_sum'])
    return  render(request, template, context)
```

the key is that you need to somehow extract the keys returned by the aggregate funcion to the context and then use it in your template

Comment: Found it :D it was paid__sum